# How to replace multiple values in a string depending on a list of keys

Tags: r

I have this data which I want to replace each value with a fixed value from another list

```
values
key1
key3;key4;key1
key2;key1
```

Here is the list that "translates" each key into something else (these are just examples so it is not enought to just change the word "key" to "code".

```
key    code
key1  code1
key2  code2
key3  code3
key4  code4
```

So the end product should look like this:

```
values
code1
code3;code4;code1
code2;code1
```

This is how I tried to solve it but got stuck:

```
values = tibble(id = 1:3, values = c("key1", "key3;key4;key1", "key2;key1"))
key_code = tibble(key = c("key1", "key2", "key3", "key4"), code = c("code1", "code2", "code3", "code4"))

values %>% 
  mutate(values = strsplit(values, ";")) %>% 
  unnest(values) %>% 
  left_join(key_code, by = c("values" = "key"))
```

This is what I get

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id code 
  <int> <chr>
1     1 code1
2     2 code3
3     2 code4
4     2 code1
5     3 code2
6     3 code1
```

From here I want to get:

```
    id code 
  <int> <chr>
1     1 code1
2     2 code3;code4;code1
3     3 code2;code1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste` or `str_c`.  Instead of `strsplit`, another option is `separate_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
values %>% 
    separate_rows(values) %>% 
    left_join(key_code, by = c("values" = "key")) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(code = str_c(code, collapse=";"))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     id code             
#  <int> <chr>            
#1     1 code1            
#2     2 code3;code4;code1
#3     3 code2;code1
```

---

Or an easier option is `str_replace` which can take a named `vector` or `list` and use that to replace the values in the string without even splitting or joining

```
values %>% 
  mutate(values = str_replace_all(values, set_names(key_code$code, key_code$key)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     id values           
#  <int> <chr>            
#1     1 code1            
#2     2 code3;code4;code1
#3     3 code2;code1
```